# How to set h2 to stream resultset?

Tags: streaming, resultset, h2

Mysql driver has options to set so that resultset will not be read completely in memory as in here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html#ResultSet.

Is there an equivalent option for H2?

Thanks,

Comment: What problem do you want to solve? This might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: ResultSets that have a large number of rows, and cannot allocate heap space in my JVM for the memory required, I want to h2 to stream the results back one row at a time

Comment: H2 should buffer the result set to disk if it's too large. This is slower (due to the additional write), but should work. Is it a performance problem? If yes, how fast is it and how fast does it need to be?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am more concern about memory consumption than performance at this point. We are using h2 with our raspherby pi on 128M jvm. The result set can be 12k rows x 150 bytes each ~ 1MB of binary data. I am just want to make sure h2 doesn't load all the data in memory causing to much GC and pausing the program.

Comment: OK thanks for explaining! Yes, for your use case, most likely server side cursors would be very helpful, as it would avoid the temporary storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H2 currently does not support server side cursors. However, it buffers large result sets to disk (as a separate file, or as a temporary table). The disadvantage is speed, but it should not be a memory usage problems.

You can set the size of the when H2 will buffer to disk using [`set max_memory_rows`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_max_memory_rows). You can append that to the database URL: `jdbc:h2:~/test;max_memory_rows=100000`.

A workaround is usually to use "keyset paging" as described in the presentation ["Pagination Done the Right Way"](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way). That would mean running multiple queries instead of one.

My plan is to implement server side cursors in H2 in the next months.

Comment: Is there a flag to control how large the result set that h2 should buffer to disk?