# Ignite Query / SqlQuery / SqlFieldsQuery: are "lazy" and "page size" actually doing anything?

Tags: h2, ignite

Some background: we are building a machine learning farm off Ignite cluster. Part of the use case is generating training data sets, which are gigantic matrices (up to billions of rows x thousands of columns in theory), one row per data entry in Ignite cache.

We are using `SqlQuery` to fetch the records matching a predicate locally on each node, then iterate over records, generate vectors, write them into an external storage for further consumption. Each node exports data independently, so for 32 nodes we end up with 32 exported data sets.

The problem: small data set generations worked OK, but larger data set generations (queries expected to return 10M+ rows per node) basically kill the entire cluster, blowing out the nodes due to OOME and GC hell. We looked at "Performance and Debugging" section of Ignite docs (https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging#result-set-lazy-load), tried lazy result set and page size settings. Nope.

The investigations (profiling, memory dumps, debugger, etc), suggested that result sets of the queries are loaded into memory completely before our code gets to read the first row, even though we are using `QueryCursor` and iterations. The `Query#pageSize` and `SqlFieldsQuery#setLazy` do not seem to have any effect on that whatsoever. Digging deeper, it turned out that H2 (that Ignite indexing is using) does not support server-side cursor in result sets at all, and can only be configured to buffer the records onto disk (even with SSDs, this is a performance non-starter). Reading through Ignite source code suggested that `Query#pageSize` and `SqlFieldsQuery#setLazy` are only used in distributed queries / scan queries, and still Ignite does full reads of result sets on the nodes into memory.

Sigh. These are remediations we thought of:

- Literally run thousands of tiny Ignite nodes with a lots of unused memory, as opposed to dozens of big ones. Looks really cost-ineffective.
- Use `h2.maxMemoryRows` set to some small value. Seems like a silly solution (memory-to-memory in the same JVM through a buffer on disk? really?).
- Ditch the `SQLQuery` / `SQLFieldsQuery`, bypass H2, use `ScanQuery`. This is a ton of work (have to parse predicate and compile them into `IgniteBiPredicate`, plus these are full table scans, therefore no index / optimization, which sort makes the whole ordeal pointless).
- Presuade [Thomas Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/382763/thomas-mueller) to do server-side cursors in H2 somehow (see 
  [How to set h2 to stream resultset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787119/how-to-set-h2-to-stream-resultset))?
- Allocate gigantic ram drives on each ignite node to buffer H2 record sets there (alright, this got weird, I'd probably stop).

The question: is our assessment correct and query result streaming is not a thing for local queries? Are there any more sensible workarounds?

Would appreciate some insight from Ignite comrades if they read this. Thanks in advance!

*UPDATE:* in case it matters, the cluster is 8 nodes as follows:

`Architecture:          x86_64
CPU(s):                32
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
CPU MHz:               2345.904
BogoMIPS:              4600.05
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   full
RAM:                   240Gb`

These are designated EC2-s with ephemeral volumes for Ignite `/data` mount.

Comment: Show please query that leads to OOME.

Comment: @MityaXMitya, the query is `SqlQuery<Object,BinaryObject>` with `limit 10000000` as predicate. Queries are running with `setLocal(true)` on each node independently in parallel (that seems to be important). The cache it is going against is approx 600M records per node. There are 8 identical nodes in the cluster, the specs are 32-CPU Xeon CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz in EC2 (Xen supervisor), dedicated. Can grab more specs if desired.

Comment: I allocated some time to build a bench test. Will post the git link here.

Comment: FYI, we did another test today after swapping the `SqlQuery` with `ScanQuery`. Not seeing any OOMEs in the cluster, but still see a significant JVM pauses (over 15 sec, at a rate of 5-20 per minute from cluster). These pauses result in client being disconnected from the cluster.

Comment: Monday update - a colleague has pointed me to this discussion: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Ignite-memory-leak-td23156.html#a23177

I wonder if it is related to what we are seeing. The GC log analysis from the cluster above confirmed we have frequent and long stop-the-world GC pauses. Hopefully isolated small scale test would help to get better readings...

Comment: Possibly relevant ignite bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-9196

Comment: What your query does? Does it use grouping or ordering? It highly depends on query when H2 has to load all results to heap to process them. Could you show your actual query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating this after seemingly solving the issue.

Note: the question was about local queries.

It looks like using `SqlFieldsQuery` with 'lazy' helped for local queries. Local `SqlQuery` seems to be ignoring the `lazy` flag.

Answer (score 0):

`lazy` does definitely do anything: for `SELECT * FROM cache` query, it's the difference between cluster failure and normal operation. `page size` should be working together with `lazy`.

Can you show your query? Also, I'm not sure that it really applies to local queries.